# Get system timestamp in wordpress

Tags: date, date-time, timestamp

My system timezone is UTC+1, MySQL is using this timezone and it's ok. Now I want to get the same timestamps in WordPress. As you know, WordPress modifies the current timezone so time() returns UTC-related time. There is a possibility to use current_time('timestamp') to get either UTC timestamp or Wordpress-timezone timestamp. But my WordPress timezone is different from the system one.

So the question is: how can I get SYSTEM timestamp inside the WordPress environment? I guess they should leave a core function for that since I can not use time() anymore.

Of course, there is a stupid solution like (time() + 3600), but I don't like it.

Comment: What do you mean "My system timezone is UTC+1"? How have you configured this? By default PHP works in UTC, unless you've set it to something else in php.ini. But if you did set the timezone with php.ini then `date()` would display the time in that timezone. So I'm not sure what you're trying to do exactly.

Comment: Also, a "timestamp" is timezone independent. It's always "measured in the number of seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT)." So it doesn't make much sense to talk about the system timestamp, since that is just `time()`. What do you intend to do with this timestamp?

Comment: @JacobPeattie UTC+1 is a timezone of my server (not PHP, not apache, I mean Ubuntu's system time). It does matter, because it's a default MySQL timezone too (system's timezone by default). What I need is to get the same timezone in the Wordpress.

Comment: The problem with wordpress is the next: Wordpress resets timezone for PHP, so time() will always return UTC+0 datestamp! I am looking for a WP core function to get the system timestamp.

Comment: WordPress does not do anything like that. Where did you get that idea?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Just try to show date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()); in the index.php (very first line of the wp code) and in the functions.php. You will see the difference.

Comment: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/functions.php#L61

Comment: current_time() is a custom function in WordPress. What of it? It doesn’t change the value of time(), a completely separate function.

Comment: @JacobPeattie Just want to show you an internal function of WP, which assumes that time()'s timezone is dropped to UTC+0. Wordpress does it for it's own goals, so you should to use current_time('timestamp') inside your WP code instead of time(). But nor time() neither current_time('timestamp') return SYSTEM time.

Answer (score -1):

You can use PHP's [`date()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function here, but usually first you'll need to run [`date_default_timezone_set`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php).  UTC+1 [looks like Central Europe time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_European_Time) from what I can tell, so here's what I'd run:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', now() );
?>
```

That will print out the current time from your server.

If you're looking to print out a timestamp from a post, you can use get_post_time and print replace the `now()` function.  Looks like this:

```
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
echo date( 'D, d M Y H:i:s', get_post_time('U', true) );
?>
```

Comment: Nah, I can't call date_default_timezone_set(). First, because I virtually don't know "system time" timezone. And second, I don't want to ruin Wordpress core logic, which is intended time()'s timezone is set to UTC+0.

Comment: Also there is no "now()" function in PHP.